# @Get('*') doesn't match empty (NestJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, routes, nestjs

Within my Nest backend I'm trying to match a url within my controller

```
@Controller('admin')
export class AdminController {
    @Get('*') 
    getAdminB(@Res() response): void {
        response.sendFile(path.resolve('./public/admin/index.html'));
    }
}
```

This should match the following URLS:

```
/admin
/admin/
/admin/anything
```

However, the above get `@Get('*')` doesn't match `/admin`.  Should I add an other route with `@Get()` or is there a fix for this?

I need this because I have to serve an angular app from `/admin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the path `@Get('/?*')` to match all routes.

### Why does this work?

Nest uses the util function [`validatePath()`](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/b634e6182d6f1c1404865f4282a657f317754d76/packages/common/utils/shared.utils.ts#L7) to build the path. When you have a prefix (`admin` in your case), then nest will always add a `/` between the prefix and the path from your route decorator unless the first char is already a `/`.

```
export const validatePath = (path?: string): string =>
  path
    ? path.charAt(0) !== '/' ? '/' + path : path
    : '';
```

So the path that is given to express will be `admin/?*` which matches any path that starts with `admin`. **Careful**, this also includes e.g. `adminarea/1`!